# How do I replace a value in my SQL output?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have the below query and would like to replace the values from the first 2 rows of the first column with something more meaningful

```
select a.conttype, c.fundn as FundName, a.perc as Percentage 
from fundchoice a, flag b,  fund c
where a.bgroup = 'A1'  
and a.bgroup = b.bgroup  
and a.bgroup = c.bgroup  
and a.refno = b.refno  
and a.conttype = b.conttype  
and a.fundcode = c.fundcode  
and a.mpfm01d >= b.mpfc01d  
and a.conttype in('EEAV', 'EERP')  
and a.refno = '00090'  
and mpfc01d = (select max(mp)                  
                 from flag                  
                 where bgroup = b.bgroup                    
                 and refno = b.refno                    
                 and conttype = b.conttype)
order by a.conttype,a.fundcode;
```

Current result is

| Conttype | FUNDNAME | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AV | S&P 500 | 100 |
| RP | S&P 500 | 100 |

I would like to replace the values as follows:

|  |
| --- |
| AV with Employee AV |
| RP with Employee Reg |

What do I need to add to my query in order to replace these values?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [DECODE()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DECODE.html) function. It would look like:  `SELECT DECODE(a.conttype, 'AV','Employee AV', 'RP', 'Employee Reg') as conttype, c.fundn as FundName, a.perc as Percentage 
from ...`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that on-the-fly with `case` expression or `decode`, but I guess that creating a **table** that contains descriptions would be worth the initial effort.

```
create table cont_type as
  select 'RV' id, 'Employee Reg' name from dual union all
  select 'AV'   , 'Employee AV'       from dual union all
  ...
```

Then join that table to current query:

```
select a.conttype, 
       t.name type_name,                               --> here 
       c.fundn as FundName, a.perc as Percentage 
from fundchoice a, flag b,  fund c, 
     cont_type t                                       --> here
where a.bgroup = 'A1'  
and a.bgroup = b.bgroup  
and a.bgroup = c.bgroup  
and a.refno = b.refno  
and a.conttype = b.conttype  
and a.fundcode = c.fundcode  
and a.mpfm01d >= b.mpfc01d  
and a.conttype in('EEAV', 'EERP')  
and a.refno = '00090'  
and mpfc01d = (select max(mp)                  
                 from flag                  
                 where bgroup = b.bgroup                    
                 and refno = b.refno                    
                 and conttype = b.conttype)
and t.id = a.conttype                                  --> here
order by a.conttype,a.fundcode;
```